# UITableVIew didSelectRowAtIndexPath can't go to new page

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

When I selected the table row, nothing happened it didn't go to ContentController and I can't find the UILabel that I declared on ContentController.h when I want to link it to resultLabel

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/31849498/Diet.zip

Comment: Someone might go through the trouble and download your project and load it up in Xcode etc. but if you want more people to see it (higher chance of someone giving an answer), you need to take the time to post code in your question so people can look at the problem without downloading anything. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked your code but with the following mistakes:-

1) navigation Controller is not present but you are calling 
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailview animated:YES];

2)In the contentController you have not given the iboutlet for uilabel. Hence no mapping is done.

remedies
1)use the presentmodelviewcontroller if you want to go from one view to another
syntax:
[self presentModalViewController:detailview animated:YES];
or
declare the uinavigation controller in the appdelegate and lauch the navigation controller inside the function didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in appdelegate.m

2)     IBOutlet UILabel *resultLabel;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *resultLabel;

replace your code with this.

*Note when ever you try to add Library objects make the iboutlet which is used for doing mapping between the object variable and object.

Comment: Oh, stupid me... I forgot to add "IBOutlet", thank you so much for helping.

Answer (score 1):

you're using `self.navigationController`, but you don't have navigation controller embedded in your application - that's why nothing happens, when you literally call:

```
[nil pushViewController: detailview animated: YES];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Solved. There's another problem as well, I can't find the UILabel on the ContentController.xib

Answer (score 1):

因為你的root view是一個view controller ，並不是一個TableViewController ,所以可能會沒有Navigationcontroller

Denis說的是對的。

Comment: 謝謝. 這個問題解決了. 但我在ContentController.xib 為什麼找不到 resultLabel

Comment: 因為你是宣告UILabel *resultLabel;而不是IBoutlet UILabel *resultLabel;
所以你沒辦法在XIB裡面找到